# Как открыть элемент списка ListView в фрагменте?

Tags: kotlin

Помогите, пожалуйста. У меня есть список ListView, нужно чтобы при нажатии на отдельный его элемент текст из этого элемента показывался во фрагменте. И что нужно указать в слушателе кнопки close во фрагменте, чтобы фрагмент закрылся без сохранения переданных ему данных? onStop()?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() { 
 lateinit var mainBindingClass: ActivityMainBinding 
 var list = ArrayList<String>() 
 
 
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { 
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) 
 mainBindingClass = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) 
 setContentView(mainBindingClass.root) 
 list.add("Оля") 
 list.add("Вася") 
 list.add("Юля") 
 } 
 
 
 private fun initListeners() { 
 mainBindingClass.lvListOfNotes.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id -> 
 val detailFragment = DetailFragment() 
 val manager = supportFragmentManager 
 val transaction = manager.beginTransaction() 
 transaction.replace(R.id.fl_container, detailFragment) 
 transaction.addToBackStack(null) 
 transaction.commit() 
 var note : String 
// не знаю как взять для note взять текст из отдельного элемента списка и передать в фрагмент
 } 
 
 }



class DetailFragment : Fragment() { 
 lateinit var detailBindingClass: FragmentDetailBinding 
 
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { 
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) 
 detailBindingClass = FragmentDetailBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) 
 setContentView(detailBindingClass.root) 
 
 } 
 
 
 override fun onCreateView( 
 inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle? 
 ): View? { 
 val view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false) 
 val tv = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvNote) 
 return view 
 
 
 var note = // здесь должно приниматься значение из MainActivity
 } 
 
 private fun initListeners() { 
 detailBindingClass.bClose.setOnClickListener { 
 onStop(); 
 } 
 
 }
override fun onPause() { 
 super.onPause() 
 } 
 
 
 override fun onAttach(context: Context) { 
 super.onAttach(context) 
 } 
 
 override fun onDetach() { 
 super.onDetach() 
 } 
 
 override fun onDestroy() { 
 super.onDestroy() 
 } 
 
 override fun onStart() { 
 super.onStart() 
 } 
 
 override fun onStop() { 
 super.onStop() 
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

надеюсь проблем перевести код из java в kotlin не возникнет

внутри `DetailFragment()` добавьте метод

```
public static DetailFragment newInstance(String s) {
    DetailFragment fragment = new FragmentSettingsNavigationRemote();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("param", s);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

что бы достать определенную строку из элемента при нажатии

```
list.get(position)
```

таким образом нужно объявить фрагмент вот так

```
val detailFragment = DetailFragment.newInstance(list.get(position))
```

а внутри самого фрагмента вы можете достать строку по "param"

```
getArguments().getString(ActivitySettings.PARAM_BREADCRUMB)
```